# Combine values from two columns into the third column

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
AUTOID --- BRANCHID ---- QUTNO
1           10           "10#1"
2           11           "11#2"
```

`AUTOID` is a primary, autogenerated column. I need to fill the `QUTNO` column with combination of values from columns `branchid` and `autoid`. How can i do these in sql server insert statement stored procedure?

Comment: If you mean INSERT of qutno, does it mean that it will get the auto incremented ID (i.e. AUTOID) and the value of BRANCHID and post it to QUTNO while it is still inserting the record? Or do you mean to say update qutno with the values of AUTOID and BRANCHID that are already existent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using a computed column?

Something like

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        AUTOID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        BRANCHID INT,
        QUTNO AS CAST(BRANCHID AS VARCHAR(25)) + '#' + CAST(AUTOID AS VARCHAR(25))
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (BRANCHID) VALUES (10),(11)

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4991)

Answer (score 6):

Make the column a computed column and set the computational expression so the two columns are concatenated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample of computed columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  --, InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
  , computed1 As Convert(varchar,QtyAvailable) + '#' + Convert(varchar, UnitPrice)
);

-- Insert values into the table.
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (QtyAvailable, UnitPrice)
VALUES (25, 2.00), (10, 1.5);

-- Display the rows in the table.
SELECT ProductID, QtyAvailable, UnitPrice, computed1
FROM dbo.Products;
```

it'll produce the output:

```
ProductID   QtyAvailable    UnitPrice   computed1
1                 25         2.00       25#2.00
2                 10         1.50       10#1.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use IDENT_CURRENT() to acheive this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (BRANCHID , QUTNO)
VALUES (@branchId, @branchId + '#' + (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.TABLE1'))))
```